# IEDriver always showing localhost title instead of given URL title

Tags: java, selenium

When driver launching the browser it is always getting open with local host 
and  then navigating to given URL but driver is not getting the current page 
title instead always showing local host title "This page can’t be 
displayed". I am posting my code and error i am getting, please tell me 
where i am wrong.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestIEBrowser {
```

public WebDriver driver;

```
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("launching IE browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.39.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser() {
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Page title: - "+strPageTitle);
        Assert.assertTrue(strPageTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Google"),
     "Page `title doesn't match");`
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        if(driver!=null) {
            System.out.println("Closing IE browser");
            driver.quit();
        }
    } }

Error    
launching IE browser
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 2.39.0.0
Listening on port 47579
Jul 31, 2017 5:43:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Page title: - This page can’t be displayed

Closing IE browser

FAILED: testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser

java.lang.AssertionError: Page title doesn't match expected [true] but found [false]

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)

    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:512)

    at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at TestIEBrowser.testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser(TestIEBrowser.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)

    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)

    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
```

Comment: Consider upgrading `Selenium` and `IEDriverServer` to v3.4.0 & `IE` to v10/11. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use driver.get() instead of driver.navigate().

Also you could try to use

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(title.isDisplayed)`

Comment: Any reason/documentation to avoid `driver.navigate().to();` ? Thanks

Comment: In my practise, some drivers don't like working with driver.navigate() or working slower then with driver.get().